# Re-assign mutable struct field of type Union{Nothing, Float64} in Julia

Tags: struct, julia, unions

Let's say I have a simple mutable struct with a field that can be a Float or Nothing

```
mutable struct Foo
    bar::Union{Nothing, Float64}
end

foo = Foo(0.42)
foo.bar = Nothing
```

If I try to assign Nothing to it, I get this error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Type{Nothing} to an object of type Float64
```

Should I define my struct differently? 
Or is there another way around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'd also get an error if you wrote `foo.bar = Float64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `foo.bar = nothing`. `Nothing` is the type of `nothing`.

Comment: that is a really bad error message though.